# Using date, and date only, in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, datepicker, jodatime

I'm writing a java program and I have been stuck for quite some while with all the Date, DateTime and so forth parts of Java Programming.

What I want is to have a DATE object only. I have a class:

## Deployment.java

```
public class Deployment {

    int id;
    LocalDate deviceDeploymentDate; //I'm unsure what this should be

    public Deployment(int id, LocalDate deviceDeploymentDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.deviceDeploymentDate = deviceDeploymentDate;
    }

    public Deployment() {
    
    }

    public LocalDate getDeviceDeploymentDate() {
        return deviceDeploymentDate;
    }

    public void setDeviceDeploymentDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.deviceDeploymentDate = date;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And I have a Date Picker in my GUI.

[image: JDatePickerImpl]

From this Date Picker I can get the date in a string format (and also change it to int year, int month and int date if needed ofc). From this I want to store some sort of DATE within my Deployment object, and I do not want the time to be part of this at all.

## Question

Which datatype should I use to do this? And how would I do?

## Misc

I have shortly looked at Joda Time, but have been unable to create a LocalDate / DateTime type from either the String or integers that I can get from the Date Picker.

Comment: You could use the type you're using already, and set the time part to 00:00:00. Then when formatting for output, don't display the time parts.

Comment: That could one way to do it, but I'd rather use a Data Type which only contains the date element. The reason is that I'm going to store the element in a SQL database and as far as I've understood the SQL database also only stores a "String" of the type "yyyy-MM-dd" (This so called "String" is however a Date type.

Comment: @Zeliax No, no serious database stores date-time types as strings. While you can ask for a string representation of the value to be generated for you as the result of a query, do not confuse that string with the actual value stored in the database. The internal storage will be implemented in a manner more efficient than strings. But you are right to want to use an appropriate data type in Java: See the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep using LocalDate(as per David's comment) and use DateTimeFormatter from Joda Time as below to convert String into LocalDate.

```
final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd");
final LocalDate dt = dtf.parseLocalDate(yourinputString);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason behind the fact that you specify them as finals?

Answer (score 3):

Joda-Time is great, but is mostly not needed since the Date-Time API in Java 8 and later. The team behind [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) even advices users on Java 8 or above to use the standard API:

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

Given this, you should use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) from the standard API, `java.time`. Your `Deployment` class can look just like it does now, just make sure to import the correct package (`java.time.LocalDate`).

Since you have access to the fields (year, month and day), you can use one of the [`of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-) methods in the API:

```
LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
```

Note that `month` and `day` starts with 1, i.e. January is month 1. In the previous Date/Calendar APIs, month counting started with 0, i.e. January was month 0. In other words, be careful if you mix the two APIs.

By the way, `java.time` has a predefined `Month` enum that might be handy instead of using integers for months:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2012, Month.January, 31);
```

Comment: Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. The Joda-Time team advises migrating to java.time.